# Why can't I access the nth element of my decayed 2D array of strings?

Tags: c

I'm messing around in C by decaying 2D arrays of strings into pointers for learning purposes.

I wrote the following that constructs a 2D array of strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 10
#define STR_LEN 20

int main() {
    // Each string in our 2D array has STR_LEN bytes of space
    char arr[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE][STR_LEN];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ARR_SIZE; j++) {
            snprintf(arr[i][j], STR_LEN, "%d %d", i, j);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ARR_SIZE; j++) {
            // Print out our string to make sure the output is good
            puts(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // Decaying my array into a pointer
    char ***p = (char ***) arr;

    puts((char *) *(p + 7));
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I decay my array into a pointer and then attempt to access the 8th item in my decayed array, I get a segfault. I'm a little surprised by this, given my intention was to save the strings to a 2D array on the Stack.

I ran Valgrind and it highlights the following line as the problem:

```
    puts((char *) *(p + 7));
```

I get an "Invalid read of size 1 1 warning" and a "Address is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd".

So the error message is telling me that I'm accessing an area of memory that isn't on the stack or heap.

So clearly something is going amiss here but being new to C, I'm not quite sure what is the issue. Have I not created a 2D array of strings on the Stack as I intended to? Or is the problem with how I'm decaying my array into a `char ***` pointer?

Comment: A pointer to pointer to pointer to char is nowhere near synonymous with an array of array of array of char. The type of `arr` used in an expression context is a pointer to first element with a type equivalent to pointer to the most-superior index type. The most-superior indexed type is `char[ARR_SIZE][STR_LEN]`. Therefore, `char (*p)[ARR_SIZE][STR_LEN] = arr;` will work.

Comment: @p4t Where is there a two-dimensional array?

Comment: Is there a typo, did you mean `snprintf()`? The call seems to imply that.

Comment: That you had to forcibly cast `arr` to `char***` to get what you have to even compile should be considered the first hint you're doing something dreadfully wrong.

Comment: @WhozCraig ahhh thank you for clarifying, I clearly still have much to learn about pointers. I'm just trying to wrap my head around the idea of the "most superiori index type" but I think I just need to sit on it for a little while more...

Comment: @unwind yep there was a typo - fixed now! Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of misconceptions here. The programmer doesn't "decay" arrays into pointers, the compiler does, implicitly. Either when an array name is used inside common expressions or when an array is declared as a function parameter.

---

> I wrote the following that constructs a 2D array of strings:

That's a 3D array of characters. It can be used as a 2D array of strings with fixed widths.

---

> `char ***p = (char ***) arr;`

This is nonsense. Arrays are not pointers, pointers are not arrays. The rules of array decay done by the compiler happens on the outer-most dimension only.

- In case of a 3D array `char arr[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE][STR_LEN];` used in an expression as `arr`, it decays into a pointer to the first element.
- The first element is a 2D array of type `char [ARR_SIZE][STR_LEN]`.
- A pointer to that first element is of type `char (*)[ARR_SIZE][STR_LEN]`.
- Which has absolutely nothing to do with `char**` nor `char***`. For now, just forget that you ever saw pointers-to-pointers-to-... because there are very few uses for them and this is not one.

Don't use casts unless you truly know what you are doing. In some 99% of all cases where you get an incompatible pointer type conversion warning... it's because you are attempting an incompatible pointer type conversion. The solution is not to make some dirty cast, but to fix the bug which is causing the warning.

---

Also don't use obfuscation when de-referencing a pointer to the first element. Don't write some unreadable `*(p + 7)`, write readable `p[7]`.